# Validate Date Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple validation date which doesn't seem to work. I wanted to ensure that the start date is not greater than the end date.

```js
function validateDate() {
  var d1 = new Date.parse(document.getElementsByName("dt1").value);
  var d2 = new Date.parse(document.getElementsByName("dt2").value);

  if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime())
    alert("Start date cannot be greater than End date");

}
```

```html
<label for="dt1">Start Date : </label><input type="date" id="dt1">
<label for="dt2">End Date : </label><input type="date" id="dt2" onfocusout="validateDate()">
```

I attached a fiddle to demostrate this better :  https://jsfiddle.net/63g99gk8/1/

I am a complete novice in doing javascript and would appreciate any advice and comments.

Comment: `Date.parse` is not a constructor so `new` is not valid. `getElementsByName` should be `getElementById`.

Comment: How are you making the input?

Comment: Allways have a look in the console. There you'll find the error `Uncaught TypeError: Date.parse is not a constructor`

Comment: What you need to know is an important thing in programming. How to debug. and then you will be saved. So you dont have to ask others to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in the code. You can directly create date object. And also use getElementById() to get values.

```js
function validateDate(e) {

 var d1 = new Date(document.getElementById("dt1").value);
 var d2 = new Date(document.getElementById("dt2").value)

 if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime())
  alert("Start date cannot be greater then End date");

}
```

```html
<label for="dt1">Start Date : </label>
<input type="date" id="dt1">
<label for="dt2">End Date : </label>
<input type="date" id="dt2" onchange="validateDate(event);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementsByName` which returns a [**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and not just the specific element. Seeing you have an `id` use `getElementById` instead.

Additionally `new Date.parse` is not valid. Use `new Date()` instead passing the value of your calendar to it as a parameter `new Date(value)`.

See Documentation on [**Date**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for a more details.

```js
var validateDate = function() {
 var d1 = new Date(document.getElementById("dt1").value);
 var d2 = new Date(document.getElementById("dt2").value);
  
 if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime())
  alert("Start date cannot be greater then End date");

}
```

```html
<label for="dt1">Start Date : </label><input type="date" id="dt1">
<label for="dt2">End Date : </label><input type="date" id="dt2" onfocusout="validateDate()">
```